# Magento 2.2.0 , Paypal Credit Issue "The payment method disallows storing objects"

Tags: onepage-checkout, payment-methods, paypal, paypal-express, magento2.2.0

I am using magento version 2.2.0 , when I try to place order using payemt method as Paypal Credit, it works fine on ckeckout/cart page, but on OnePage checkout I get the error "The payment method disallows storing objects".

I see Following in the console

HEADERS

Request URL: www.mydomai.com/rest/default/V1/guest-carts/1234f163c7f626d7d87096bcb5b622d1/set-payment-information

Request Method: POST

Status Code: 400 Bad Request

Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

RESPONSE

{"message":"The payment disallows storing objects."}

Please let me know where can I resolve this, without upgrading my current magento version.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Magento bug that was allegedly fixed in Magento 2.2.4, though there still seem to be reports that it happens on more recent versions:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/11885

This third-party module is supposed to fix it according to [Fooman](https://magento2-support.fooman.co.nz/article/1590-paypal-error-message-the-payment-disallows-storing-object), though I have not tested it personally:

https://github.com/CopeX/PaypalFix